# Filtering similar images in 2 numpy.ndarray in effective way

Tags: python, image, numpy, machine-learning

Currently I play with some ML algorithms and I have 2 sets of images (train and validation sets) which I store in in np.ndarray. Images are greyscale, size is 28x28. I have about 200000 of train images and smth like 20000 of validation images. I know that my dataset is not ideal and:
- In each dataset I could have same or almost same images
- There could be an overlap between validation and train set

Intuition tells me that same or similar images in train and validation set could hurt performance of my ML algorithms so I decided to try to sanitize my datasets.

I could easily sanitize dataset by combining both sets, and killing same images using hashing, for example md5 hashing with building incrementally a dictionary of md5 hashes and copying to new ndarray only those images whose md5 hash do not exist in dictionary of hashes yet.

But! I am not sure how to kill one of the images in case there is another image which is *almost* same as other image. For example when out of 28x28 pixels just couple have different value. Any ideas how to come up with effective metric of distance between to images? Under effective I also mean that it preferably should work relatively fast, since I am not sure if pixel-wise comparison will be a good idea. Also it will be useful if someone provide any insight into if there is any real good in sanitizing dataset by removing similar images?

Comment: You could use algorithms targeting *perceptual hashing*. While it might be not optimal for your case (very small images), i once coded something like this [here](https://github.com/sschnug/pyVideoHash/blob/master/frame_hash.pyx) (there is also the relevant paper in the comments which can guide you too similar work; the stats-based approaches are easy to implement). While i'm not an expert, i like your idea of removing near-dupes (although there might be some use-cases where this is counter-productive; where these tiny-diffs are really import). Cleaning up should help generalization i think.

Comment: @sascha thanks, the idea seems interesting, but I think it is a bit of an overkill. I need to filter out the things which are REALLY similar and on big number of images, so I'd prefer to look for some simpler approach. But I will keep in mind your suggestion :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the sum of the distance in RGB space between the two images by doing something like

```
(((a - b)**2).sum(axis=2)**0.5).sum()
```

However you have to be very careful as you will get a big difference between two images that are actually very similar (i.e. where

```
b = numpy.roll(a, 1, axis=0)
```

A neural net might be an effective way to determine the similarity between images! But are you training your system with raw images? It is normally better to do some perception style preprocessing as per @sascha's suggestion (when I looked at this recently I ended up doing luminance->edge->H.O.G. and found it was faster to use pure numpy than scikit-image https://github.com/paddywwoof/Machine-Learning/blob/master/image_processor.py) and obviously you should test for distance between the results **after** preprocessing.

Comment: Actually the whole preprocessing  thing is actually done to perform the training of neural network, so... It would be odd to train one neural network to sanitize data in order to train other neural network :) Thanks for idea of distance measure, will try it out though I am a bit skeptical due to the point you mentioned

Comment: @MaximHaytovich, I suppose you could do offsets one pixel in each direction as well, i.e. ((a[:,-1] - b[1:])**2) etc. but obviously that would take (at least) five times as long. And it would miss offsets of two pixels, or the same image but rotated by a small angle.